# Best type of disk image to use on NAS to archive Mac system copies on a NAS

Tags: backup, nas, bootable-disk, sparsebundle, disk-image

I bought a shiny new NAS with plenty of space. I also have quit a few old pysical external hard drives with bootable macOS system copies: I always make a copy of my system which I store away when I upgrade my macOS version. So I have Leopard, Lion, Mavericks and El Capitan drives...

Now I want to declutter, but still keep the data "just in case". So I though I create disk images on the NAS and copy the mirrored systems over (with Carbon Copy Cloner or SuperDuper). - And in case I really need them again I restore them back to a drive and can hopefully boot them up again. Here my question:

**What is the best type of disk image to use:** **Sparse bundle**, **sparse image**, or **fixed disk image?**

I want as much reliability as possible and I'm not planning to write to the images after copying.

Answer (score 2):

For archival images, I'd use the "compressed" format (which I think you'd consider "fixed", but it's one of a number of fixed-size formats). The sparse formats are useful for when you want the image to be able to expand later, when you add to them... which is pretty irrelevant for archived systems. There's also a fixed-size read-write format, and a read-only (uncompressed) format, which'll store the same thing, but take up more space for no good reason.

All the versions you mention will be in HFS+ (aka Mac OS Extended) format. In my experience, the best way to image an HFS+ volume is to mount it (note: don't try to image the volume you're running from at the time), open Disk Utility, choose File menu > New Image > Image from Folder, and select the top level of the volume as the "folder" to image. In the save dialog, make sure Image Format is set to Compressed, and it's best to save it somewhere local (and copy it to the NAS afterward). Once it's finished, choose Images > Scan Image for Restore, and have that process the newly-created image. *Then* copy it to the NAS.

Why image "from Folder" rather than from the device? Because it creates a cleaner image (files all defragmented, etc) but preserves everything that matters (i.e. if the original was bootable, you can restore the image and the result will be bootable). It also makes the image just big enough for the files, since it doesn't include all the empty space in the original volume. Including the empty space can cause trouble if you ever need to restore it to a smaller volume.

Why "Scan Image for Restore"? So you can use Disk Utility's Restore feature to restore it to a disk later (or use the command-line `asr` tool to do the same thing). You could do the scan process later, but I prefer to do it immediately, so the image'll be ready to go if I ever need it.

Comment: Cool. Does this work with Caralina (and Big Sur) as well? I have heard the new OSes make it impossible to copy the complete disk…

Comment: Apple switched the startup volume format to APFS starting in High Sierra (and then complicated it further with a split-volume format starting in Catalina). My understanding is that it *is* possible to image these, but I haven't done it so I don't know the best process.

Comment: Yep, the split-volume format is a pain - but that’s for another question…

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is often also the most reliable - I would use a simple bit-for-bit identical copy (perhaps this is what you call a "fixed disk image").

Such an image can be written back to the physical hard drive again and be able to boot up. You'll also be able to mount the file system inside the image as a virtual, read-only drive in order to inspect and copy files.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. How do I create such a bit-for-bit copy on the NAS? (BTW, with fixed disk image I mean a non-resizable, non-sparse disk image (`.dmg`).)

Comment: You haven't said anything about what kind of NAS you have, so it's impossible for me to say so - you would need to look at the manuals for that NAS. A common NAS is Synology DSM based ones - there you can connect the drive and use the "dd" command for creating the image.

Comment: Yep, my NAS is a “Syno”.  So you suggest connecting the drives physically to the NAS? Well, I won’t be able to do this with all drives, I have some FireWire drives… But and interesting approach nonetheless!

Comment: Well, I didn't actually write it as a suggestion as such - I assumed this was what you were already doing as you wrote that you were creating the images on the NAS. It doesn't matter if you connect the drive to a Mac or to the NAS directly really. If you connect it to a Mac, make sure the volumes on the drive are not mounted (if they are, eject them with Finder or Disk Utility) and again use dd to create the disk image.

Comment: If you choose to do it on the Mac you'll need to copy the images over to the NAS afterwards ofcourse. So creating it directly on the NAS is usually much faster, unless you haven't got a fast USB interface on the NAS.